# Is there a way to get the effect of combining grep -v with grep -A?

Tags: text-processing, grep

Is there a way, either with `grep` or something else, to (in effect) combine `grep -v` and `grep -A`?  That is, rather than *include* everything for x lines after a string, *exclude* everything.

Quick reminder for those who forget their grep switches:
  `cat file.txt | grep -v blah`  filters out 'blah', the opposite of normal grep
  `cat file.txt | grep -A7 foo`  will display 7 lines after each occurance of 'foo'
(Yes I'm aware that `cat` is unnecessary here.  But I find it much more readable when you string together a lot of `grep` statements to do it this way.)

Simply saying
  `cat file.txt | grep -A100 bar | grep -vA100 foo`
will not work.  "Working" would be defined as displaying everything (up to 100 lines) between the line matching 'bar' and the line matching 'foo'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a simple way of extracting all chunks from a `bar` to a `foo` with sed:

```
sed -n '/bar/,/foo/p'
```

or with awk:

```
awk '/bar/, /foo/'
```

If you want to truncate the chunks, it's a little more complicated (in awk; in sed it's a lot more complicated). Here's a solution:

```
awk -vmax_lines_per_chunk=100 '
    /bar/ {n=max_lines_per_chunk}
    /foo/ {if (n) print; n=0}
    n {--n; print}
'
```

Comment: An interesting difference between the simple sed and awk versions: the awk version stops at bar if foo also matches bar.  For example, imagine this inside a function: `cat ~/.ssh/config | awk "/Host ${1}$/, /Host /"` to get everything from the line with Host and $1 up until the next line with Host.  awk sees that the first line matches foo and stops there.  It makes perfect sense, of course, but sed fits my needs better here.